# Live and living as an adjective

Tags: difference

I was at an English lesson and I said “a live organism”, but the teacher immediately interrupted and said “you should have said “a living organism””

“I didn’t catch that” said I. and a classmate of mine said as the teacher had done. Then I told them that “ a live something and a living something are both correct because they are both adjectives”

What is the difference between these ones?
I know that there has already been another question, but an answer has not been chosen, I have  also seen some answers which are different from the ones in this website.

Comment: an answer has not been chosen, I have also seen some answers which are different to the ones in this website.

Comment: it doesn't matter much (whether OP's accepted an answer): people in that thread made good points which shed light on your question

Comment: "Live" is an adjective, but "living" is a verb. It fails all the usual tests for adjectivehood. Similar meanings, though, and they both modify "organism" I haven't checked, but I suspect that most people would say "living".

Comment: I think it's a matter of convention, not grammar. We do speak of, for example 'transporting live animals', but biologists always refer to a 'living organism' rather than a 'live' one. Your teacher was just prompting you to use the standard expression.

Comment: I checked with Google n-gram, and as I suspected "living" is by far the most commonly used modifier of "organism";see here: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+organism%2Cliving+organism&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20organism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliving%20organism%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

Living can act like an adjective (technically a verb functioning as an attribute modifier [see BillJ]) that means "live". As such, both are correct. "A living organism" is more natural though.

Comment: Yes, but "living" is not an adjective but a verb serving as a modifier.

Comment: "Living" can be an adjective. See the last definition here: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=living   It even uses "living creatures" as an example there.

Comment: Golden rule: Don't use dictionaries for grammar!  Here are 3 tests that prove it's a verb:  (a) “Living” can’t be modified by “very” (we can't say *a very living organism"); (b) It can’t occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like “become” (we can’t say *“It became quite living”); (c) It can’t occur as complement to complex-transitive verbs like “find” (we can’t say *“I found it quite living”).

Comment: Incidentally, I only mentioned the grammatical point as a matter of interest for you. It's probably more advanced grammar than what you're used to, but far more accurate. Compare also, “a sleeping child” / “the gleaming showroom” / “three steadily melting ice-creams”. In those examples, “sleeping”, “gleaming” and “melting” are not adjectives but verbs functioning as attributive modifiers, for the same reason that "living" can't be an adjective.

Comment: It's probably more advanced grammar than a great many of us are used to!